# Flutter Web - Authentication. User ID lost on hot reload

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am very new to Flutter Web and have been pulling my hair out over this one. This is exactly how I authenticate my users on mobile but for some reason when I use hot reload on flutter web the user authentication is lost and returns null and shows the CircularProgressIndicator(CPI).

Why is it doing this? If null is called then surely it should show the LoginPage() - which is does when the page is initially loaded - but as soon as I hot reload it returns null and the CPI.

Further - I added a print statement to help me keep track of the user calls - and noticed each time I navigate to a new page the user id is printed and wondering why this is?

What I would like to achieve:

1. Landing page directs user to login page if snapshot.data == null
2. Landing page directs user to home page if snapshot.data != null
3. Return a circularprogressindicator if ConnectionState.waiting
4. Fix the error as described above

   ```
   class Landing extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final auth = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context, listen: false);
   return StreamBuilder(
     stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
         User user = snapshot.data;
         print(user);
         return user == null ? LoginPage() : HomePage();
       } else
         return Scaffold(
           body: Center(
             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
           ),
         );
     },
   );
    }
     }
   ```

Comment: Please provide a specific question what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I think the problem lies in that your snapshot always has a connection state of waiting on the reload. If this is the case, a potential solution could be wrapping your `onAuthStateChanged` stream in a `BehaviorSubject` from RxDart. Then, you can provide an `initialData` in your StreamBuilder to the `BehaviorSubject`'s `value` and it will remember the most currently signed in user, if I am not mistaken (and the stream will always have an initialData that is correct).
I could turn this into an answer if you would like a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the program via F5 rather than flutter run -d chrome
Running the program via F5 allows one to press the hot reload button on VScode but importantly hot reload is currently not available on Flutter Web.

I believe, in part, this has answered my question.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing a stream into a Stateless widget. 
Change Stateless widget to stateful widget this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't think this is a fix. StreamBuilder does not require a StatefulWidget.

Comment: What about your provider?